# Как изменить много текста не используя мультикурсор

Tags: sublime-text-3, hotkeys, edit

Есть код

```
<div class="div"></div>
    <blocl-1></blocl-1>
    <blocl-2></blocl-2>
    <blocl-3></blocl-3>
    <blocl-4></blocl-4>
    <blocl-5></blocl-5>
    <blocl-6></blocl-6>
    <blocl-7></blocl-7>
    <blocl-8></blocl-8>
    <blocl-9></blocl-9>
    <blocl-10></blocl-10>
    <blocl-11></blocl-11>
    <blocl-12></blocl-12>
    <blocl-13></blocl-13>
    <blocl-14></blocl-14>
    <blocl-15></blocl-15>
    <blocl-16></blocl-16>
    <blocl-17></blocl-17>
    <blocl-18></blocl-18>
    <blocl-19></blocl-19>
    <blocl-20></blocl-20>
    <blocl-21></blocl-21>
    <blocl-22></blocl-22>
    <blocl-23></blocl-23>
    <blocl-24></blocl-24>
    <blocl-25></blocl-25>
    <blocl-26></blocl-26>
    <blocl-27></blocl-27>
    <blocl-28></blocl-28>
    <blocl-29></blocl-29>
    <blocl-30></blocl-30>
    <blocl-31></blocl-31>
    <blocl-32></blocl-32>
    <blocl-33></blocl-33>
    <blocl-34></blocl-34>
    <blocl-35></blocl-35>
    <blocl-36></blocl-36>
    <blocl-37></blocl-37>
    <blocl-38></blocl-38>
    <blocl-39></blocl-39>
    <blocl-40></blocl-40>
    <blocl-41></blocl-41>
    <blocl-42></blocl-42>
    <blocl-43></blocl-43>
    <blocl-44></blocl-44>
    <blocl-45></blocl-45>
    <blocl-46></blocl-46>
    <blocl-47></blocl-47>
    <blocl-48></blocl-48>
    <blocl-49></blocl-49>
    <blocl-50></blocl-50>
    <blocl-51></blocl-51>
    <blocl-52></blocl-52>
    <blocl-53></blocl-53>
    <blocl-54></blocl-54>
    <blocl-55></blocl-55>
    <blocl-56></blocl-56>
    <blocl-57></blocl-57>
    <blocl-58></blocl-58>
    <blocl-59></blocl-59>
    <blocl-60></blocl-60>
    <blocl-61></blocl-61>
    <blocl-62></blocl-62>
    <blocl-63></blocl-63>
    <blocl-64></blocl-64>
    <blocl-65></blocl-65>
    <blocl-66></blocl-66>
    <blocl-67></blocl-67>
    <blocl-68></blocl-68>
    <blocl-69></blocl-69>
    <blocl-70></blocl-70>
    <blocl-71></blocl-71>
    <blocl-72></blocl-72>
    <blocl-73></blocl-73>
    <blocl-74></blocl-74>
    <blocl-75></blocl-75>
    <blocl-76></blocl-76>
    <blocl-77></blocl-77>
    <blocl-78></blocl-78>
    <blocl-79></blocl-79>
    <blocl-80></blocl-80>
    <blocl-81></blocl-81>
    <blocl-82></blocl-82>
    <blocl-83></blocl-83>
    <blocl-84></blocl-84>
    <blocl-85></blocl-85>
    <blocl-86></blocl-86>
    <blocl-87></blocl-87>
    <blocl-88></blocl-88>
    <blocl-89></blocl-89>
    <blocl-90></blocl-90>
    <blocl-91></blocl-91>
    <blocl-92></blocl-92>
    <blocl-93></blocl-93>
    <blocl-94></blocl-94>
    <blocl-95></blocl-95>
    <blocl-96></blocl-96>
    <blocl-97></blocl-97>
    <blocl-98></blocl-98>
    <blocl-99></blocl-99>
    <blocl-100></blocl-100>
    <blocl-101></blocl-101>
```

Необходимо исправить blocl-$ на block-$
Как это сделать без мультикурсора т.к выделять каждый блок мультикурсором это долго

Comment: Выделяешь один `blocl-$` двойным кликом жмешь `ctrl+f` затем снизу в правом углу жмешь `find all`

Comment: Это так не функционирует я просто найду выделенный текст и мне подсветятся все совпадения

Comment: `3.2.2 (BUILD 3211)` всё работает.

Comment: @Rudi `ctrl+f` для поиска предназначен а вопрос стоит как заменить текст (мысль в том что поиском текст не заменишь поэтому твой ответ не правильный)

Comment: `find all` выделяет все совпадения в открытом файле, потом просто набираешь текст. Ну ты отметь еще один ответ на свой же вопрос, как правильный.. Всё таки с 1 октября ищешь.. В vs не получилось?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нажимаешь `ctrl+h`
2. В поле `Find` вводишь текст где ошибка
3. В поле `Replace` вводишь текст без ошибки
4. Нажимаешь `Replace All`

[image: пример]